# My array is returning zero. I have to use a multidimensional array but I am not sure how to use it

Tags: java, android, arraylist

This is my code in main, retrieving set of values from firebase

```
List<model> weather = new ArrayList<model>();

Query dbQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("NeuralNetwork");

    dbQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            //Model
            model m = dataSnapshot.getValue(model.class);

            int prev = m.getPrevious();
            int hu = m.getHumidity();
            int tem = m.getTemperature();
            int wi = m.getWind();
            int nw = m.getNewValue();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "value of temp" + temp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            weather.add(new model(prev, tem, hu, wi, nw));

        }
```

I have to retrieve all the values in an arraylist weather. The image shows my firebase, I have to loop through the nodes and get the child values:

[image: The image shows my firebase, I have to loop through the nodes and get the child values]

Answer (score 0):

I hope you define model class constructor and also get data used below code:

```
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;
// put below two line in onCreate method.
mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("usersDb/UserTable");

mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { // here pass your firebase database instance..
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            weather.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                model model = postSnapshot.getValue(model.class);
                weather.add(model);

            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```